# Show Selected Items Before Removing from Database

Tags: javascript, php

I've been researching how to do this and I can't find any helpful links so I'm asking here.

I have table on my website with data from my database. Each item has a delete checkbox next to it. If the user checks these boxes then hits the delete button, they are prompted with a message asking them if they are sure they want to delete the items. If they say yes, then the items are removed. I'd like to show what they selected in the confirmation box.

Example: Let's say they selected item4, item8, and item9, then clicked on delete. I'd want the prompt to say:

"Are you sure you want to delete the selected items?

item4

item8

item9"

I'm not sure how to even start this. Here's my current delete button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected item(s)?');"/>
```

Comment: Instead of return confirm, run a function and in that function, get the value of the item next to the clicked checkbox, then append it within the confirmation confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete"+item);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript for this, something like below will work (pseudo code);

```
<!-- Add the onclick handler -->
<input type="submit" onclick="submitOnClick();" value="Delete" />

// Javascript function
function submitOnClick() {

   var ret = "";
   var table = getTable();
   for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

      if (row.checked) {

         ret += row.innerText + " ";
      }
   }

   alert('Are you sure you want to delete the selected items of " + ret);
}
```

Depending how your HTML is setup/structured you may have to change things to get it working properly.

Hoped this helped.